# Installation type/Something else not continuing 18.10

Tags: 18.10, external-hdd

I like to think that I have a great knowledge of computers, but I haven't used any sort of Linux until a day ago. So, don't beat me up if I mess up any Linux-y terminology or if I call something another thing etc.

Anyways.

I'm trying to install 18.10 on an external HDD. I go through all the regular steps as if I was installing on a Internal HDD. Then, I choose "Something else". I partition My HDD as "Ext4" and the mount point as "/". After, I pick G-Drive mobile USB (my external HDD) as "Device for bootloader installation". Finally when I click install now, nothing happens... I click it again, same result. Thats all the installer does. (I have already tried to reinstall the installer).

Edit: I've tried everything in the comments.
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.   If I install Ubuntu (or a flavor) I always select the check-install-media option first, to ensure the download completed successfully & write to install-media was perfect. You'll see a something-in-rectangle & person-in-circle on booting where you press a key and a menu appears with check-install-media.  If that's all good, then I think about installing. The device where you place bootloader is device/bios/setting dependent and may not be the drive you install Ubuntu to (ie. not g-drive-usb) but internal drive. I'd check-install-media first if I was you though

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did the check install media earlier today just to make sure, to no avail.

Comment: Does your machine boot with UEFI? or legacy?  (till will be setup by whatever OS & how it was installed for whatever is on your internal-drive)  If not setup with legacy boot (ie. uEFI), you may need to provide a pointer to the system's efi partition (/boot/efi) on your internal drive; and the installer won't 'install' until all requirements are met. I don't know much about your hardware and thus what requirements are detected as needed, but something like this hasn't been setup is my guess.

Comment: My machine does both. I don't for sure know if its UEFI or Legacy, but I believe it's UEFI. If you need the system specs here they are: Dell Optiplex 790, i5 2400, GTX 750Ti, 320GB internal HDD (Windows 10).

Comment: I'm heading to bed. I hope we can continue troubleshooting tomorrow. Thank you!!

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.